# Is there a better way to put together physics colliders for multiple groups in Phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, I have 7 Physics groups, and they all collide with each other, and so far, my collision detector looks like this:

```js
this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.bottomQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.charmQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.downQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.strangeQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.topQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.photons, this.upQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.bottomQuarks, this.bottomQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.bottomQuarks, this.charmQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.bottomQuarks, this.downQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.bottomQuarks, this.strangeQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.bottomQuarks, this.topQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.bottomQuarks, this.upQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.charmQuarks, this.charmQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.charmQuarks, this.downQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.charmQuarks, this.strangeQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.charmQuarks, this.topQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.charmQuarks, this.upQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.downQuarks, this.downQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.downQuarks, this.strangeQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.downQuarks, this.topQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.downQuarks, this.upQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.strangeQuarks, this.strangeQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.strangeQuarks, this.topQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.strangeQuarks, this.upQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.topQuarks, this.topQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.topQuarks, this.upQuarks);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.upQuarks, this.upQuarks);
```

I feel like a loop of sorts might help with this, but I'm not sure how I would Implement that, and I would like to add more physics groups in, so is there anyway to condense the physics colliders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can just put the gameObjects/list that should collide into arrays, like so:

```
this.physics.add.collider(
    [this.photons, this.bottomQuarks, this.charmQuarks, ...],
    [this.photons, this.bottomQuarks, this.charmQuarks, ...]);
```

you just have to only pick the list, that should collide with each other.
*([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Factory.html#collider__anchor))*